# passing $SOURCE_COMMIT to Dockerfile commands on docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, git-revision

I am building docker image for a service at hub.docker.com. During compilation, the commit hash of the source is passed as an argument to CMake (so that it can be embedded in the version information). According to [Advanced options for Autobuild and Autotest](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/), the commit hash is automatically available as `SOURCE_COMMIT` environment variable.

In order to call cmake with that information, it is going as follows -- I am not sure this labyrinth is the most straightforward way:

## 1. `hooks/build`

This takes care of actually passing the variable to docker build (taken from [this example](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/#build-hook-examples)):

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build  --build-arg SOURCE_COMMIT=$SOURCE_COMMIT -f $DOCKERFILE_PATH -t $IMAGE_NAME .
```

## 2. `Dockerfile`

The value is grabbed using those two lines:

```
ARG SOURCE_COMMIT                  # get it from the --build-arg
ENV SOURCE_COMMIT $SOURCE_COMMIT   # set shell variable (of the same name)
```

and finally is passed to cmake in

```
RUN cmake -DGIT_REVISION_HASH=$SOURCE_COMMIT # and so on ...
```

---

In summary, an environment variable of the builder shell is passed as build argument, then obtained and assigned to inner shell environment variable which is then expanded and passed as cmake argument.

Did I miss something or does it have to be this complex?

Comment: This is how I've always done it too. I don't think there's another way.

Comment: Thanks :) I am sorry to hear that it is non-straightforward. I took me a while to figure it out (no example showing these pieces together) thus I thought something's wrong. Could you post your comment as asnwer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've always done it too. I don't think there's another way.

In fact, I think it was intended to be this way.

> The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time to the builder with the docker build command using the --build-arg = flag. If a user specifies a build argument that was not defined in the Dockerfile, the build outputs a warning.

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)